What is the difference between relative and content clause?
I asked ChatGPT about the role of the second ‘that’ in this passage. It answered that the word ‘that’ basically functions as a content clause. I wonder if the answer given by ChatGPT is correct. If so, what is the difference between a relative clause and a content clause?
Here is the passage:

View (1) is the view that human beings have equal inherent worth as persons independently of our responses to them, and that the impartiality of our love for them is a response to this equality.


It might help you to note that the second that is syntactically optional, since you can assume implied repetition of the first instance anyway. The second assertion refers back to and expands on the first: View (1) is the view that human beings have equal inherent worth as persons independently of our responses to them. View (1) also holds that the impartiality of our love for human beings is a response to their equal inherent worth as persons.

Are you aware that the first that also heads up a content clause? https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/that-clauses

Consider:
He told me that the earth is flat -> "that the earth is flat" gives the content of what he told you.
"I imagine that your car is rather fast." "that your car is rather fast" gives the content of what you imagine.
The man that was wearing the hat was talking - that was wearing the hat is a relative clause as it relates to an attribute of "the man".
Edit to add
"I know what you did." -> "what you did" is a content clause. It gives the content of what I know.

Content clauses map to quotes: He told me "The earth is flat." / I imagine {Your car is rather fast.} [this one, inner dialogue; these often shown in italics] // The man that was wearing the hat ⥇.

The content of what he told you would be a quote, wouldn't it? However, it can also be a content summation: "I know what you did." -> "what you did" is a content clause.

Here, with a wh-clause, it's an embedded question. I know the answer to the question "What did you do?" ... "What I did / was done by you is: 'Quote.' " There's an associated message (not necessarily a spoken one). 'I know what the notice said.'

@EdwinAshworth Your comment is a distraction and unhelpful. It is quite possible to describe"what you did" as an "embedded question" (although I would not.) A content clause contains the contents of something - in this case "What I know".  Essentially it does not differ from "I told him what I know."  You may wish to have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_clause for greater clarification.

'Content clause', coined by Jespersen, obviously has a semantic connection. With declarative (that-) content clauses, the correspondence to a statement or thought, suspicion etc is clear. With interrogative content clauses, there's an associated query. It's unhelpful to underspecify 'content', as even parentheticals contain something or other.

Content clauses have already been discussed here (though John Lawler states 'Content clause is a vague definition that adds nothing; that's why grammarians don't use the term.')

@EdwinAshworth So, "content clause" is "vague", and yet you are able to define them -> "Content clauses map to quotes" - I don't think you can have it both ways, especially as "content clause" is in the question and also commonly used (see Wiki, Google or any other search engine) and understood.  (Do you recognise the fallacy in "that's why grammarians don't use the term."?)

It's the use of a commonly understood word ('content') in an unfamiliar way, a stipulative definition, that I'm saying needs explaining decently. Your addendum helps.
